z-index and stacking context confusing
I want to use clip-path to alter the look of my background color but no matter what I do it always comes up on top covering ALL of my content.I understand that something is creating another context inside but I don't know which one it is and why it doesn't stay on top of the header with z-index:0 and if this is becuase that the header is the parent of all the others,how can I set it up that way.
header {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0);
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.header-container {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.img-container {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.bottom-center {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  right: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  transform: translate(50%, -10%);
}
.header-main {
  display: grid;
  background-color: white;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  max-width: 500px;
  align-self: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 45px -19px rgba(66, 68, 90, 1);
}

.icon-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}
.header-title {
  align-self: end;
}
.header-icons img {
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;

 <header>
      <div class="header-background">
        <div class="header-container">
          <div class="img-container">
            <img src="./img/author.jpg" alt="The photo of the author" />
            <div class="bottom-center">Author</div>
          </div>
          <div class="header-main">
            <div class="header-title"><h1>About me</h1></div>
            <div class="header-desc">
            </div>
            <div class="header-icons">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

I tried to set up the background as the separate div but it also didn't work
